# Use imported const in component without setting it as local variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to

```
import {MY_CONST} from '../const-file.js';

const myComponent = {
  controller: class {
    consturctor() {
    }
  },
  template: `
  <p>{{MY_CONST}}</p>
  `
}
```

instead of having to set the variable as local variable like this?

```
import {MY_CONST} from '../const-file.js';

const myComponent = {
  controller: class {
    consturctor() {
       this.MY_CONST = MY_CONST;
    }
  },
  template: `
  <p>{{$ctrl.MY_CONST}}</p>
  `
}
```

I find it a bit redundant to import and set the const everytime I need to use it and I'm pretty sure I'm missing on something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use it in a component like `<p>{{MY_CONST}}</p>`. There's no way how Angular compiler can know about the existence of `MY_CONST` local variable.

It's possible to hard-code it to template in ES6 like

```
template: `<p>${MY_CONST}</p>`
```

Or in ES5:

```
template: '<p>' + MY_CONST + '</p>'
```

This will certainly better for performance than template binding but may be not enough flexible. This mostly depends on what exactly MY_CONST is.

Notice that this won't work when a template is contained in separate file and loaded with `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it anywhere in the component, but you cannot use it in a `template` without being a property of your controller. However, for a constant you don't *need* it to be part of dynamic the template substitution, just use

```
const myComponent = {
  controller: class {},
  template: `
  <p>${MY_CONST}</p>
  `
}
```